# How can I change physical memory in a mapreduce/hive job?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a Hive `INSERT OVERWRITE` query on an EMR cluster with 40 worker nodes and single master node.

However, while running the `INSERT OVERWRITE` query, as soon as I get to
`Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 180529.86 sec`
this state, I get the following error:

```
Ended Job = job_1599289114675_0001 with errors
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Container [pid=9944,containerID=container_1599289114675_0001_01_041995] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.2 GB of 7.5 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1599289114675_0001_01_041995 :
```

I'm not sure how can I change the 1.5 GB physical memory number. In my configurations, I don't see such a number, and I don't understand how that 1.5 GB number is being calculated.
I even tried changing the `"yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio":"5"` to 5 as suggested in some forums. But irrespective of this change, I still get the error.

This is how the job starts:

```
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 942
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 910; number of reducers: 942
```

And this is how my [configuration file](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/7cdd47e7fe0013ab3384f43740a87e29) looks like for the cluster. I'm unable to understand what settings do I have to change to not run into this issue. Could it also be due to **Tez** settings? Although I'm not using it as the engine.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While opening hive console, append the following to the command

```
--hiveconf mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8192 --hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192 --hiveconf mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx7600M
```

Incase you still get the Java heap error, try increasing to higher values, but make sure that the mapreduce.map.java.opts doesn't exceed mapreduce.map.memory.mb.